# Eclipse doesn't download dependencies for Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, download

[image: Here is the message that I received when i tried to create a new Maven Project]

I've searched on internet about this problem and i saw there are a lot of people with same problem. But non of the solutions that I found helped me.
I'm not using proxy, my firewall is disable, I'm beginner in Java and really bored because i really want practice.
I will appreciate your help.
Thanks

pom file.

> `

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.teste</groupId>
  <artifactId>teste</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>teste</name>
</project>
```

`
[image: After done the mvn eclipse:eclipse on prompt]

Please guys i don't wanna open anoter question in Stack Overflow.
I have no ideia what can I do here...

Comment: Can you post ur pom file here?

Comment: Try once by deleteing everything in the .m2 repo

Comment: Where can I find this .m2 repo???

Comment: try to run maven from command line, and not from eclipse, and see if it is maven problem or eclipse's. this will narrow the prob.

Comment: .m2 is generally in  : C:/Users/User_Name/

Comment: I cleaned the folder but still not working, how can i run maven from command line @OhadR??

Comment: you run maven from command line using the command mvn. when you want to build your project, most commonly the command is mvn clean install. please note that "maven" home dir should be in your path. http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html

Comment: I got the same error @OhadR

Answer (score 0):

[image: preferences]Verify your eclipse maven settings. https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzKLN.png

Comment: It wasn't but even when copy your config, It didn't work I tried to update the project but I got more errors.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your pom file is ok, I would recommend doing all this from the command line. the maven plugin for eclipse is jenky. to build at the command line, first close eclipse. then go to your project folder and type:

```
mvn package
```

then type

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

this will create a new eclipse workspace file. open eclipse and you should have all the dependencies resolved.

you might also want to read [Maven in 5 Minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

Comment: may i see the warning text?

Comment: i put the image on my post @David

Comment: ok - two thoughts. first, are you using the m2e plugin for eclipse? second - how far along are you in this project? are you willing to start from scratch? It's super-easy to build the project from the command line using maven, build the eclipse workspace file, then import the ready-made project into eclipse.

Comment: yes for the first question and i've just opened this project to try fix this issue.If you can help me build project from command line i would like to but everytime that want build a new project i have to use the command line,that's it?

Comment: have to? no you shouldn't have to but in my experience it's just easier to do it the command line way than the plugin way.

Comment: the link I posted has the steps. the command you want is: 



mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false

(fill in your own info where appropriate). from there do the mvn eclipse:eclipse thing, open eclipse, close the other project, then import the new one.

Comment: i just copy and paste it on my command line and i'm getting the same warning as before.

Comment: warning or error? I just installed maven and tried the command (cut-and-paste so it's verbatim what I posted) and it worked perfectly.

Comment: It's warning and error in the end,It's so strange because it's just in my computer but i didin't now why it's happened and don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: hmm - this is interesting : 

http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/maven-metadata-xml-Error-td5759165.html

Comment: are you at work or perhaps connected to a network with some kind of restriction in place prohibiting certain kinds of downloads?

Comment: The problem is that i'm not using proxy i'm at home.

Comment: It certainly looks like the issue is that you are subject to a restriction on your network that precludes you from downloading the necessary artifacts from http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. You say you are at home..have you VPNed into your work network? If not, then perhaps some other network overlord has decided what is best for you. If on a corporate network, it may be that you can tweak Maven's settings.xml file to point to a local repository that might contain the dependency you seek.

Comment: No i haven't, it's just me that lives here, i really sad that all this solution didn't work.

Comment: hmm - do you live near a coffee shop or someplace that has free wifi? you can get a snack and see if switching networks doesn't ameliorate the issue.

Comment: I can try tonight at my girlfriend's house and post here the result.

Comment: Hi guys I tried on a different network all the ways that you showed me,it didn't work , and I tried as well with another notebook that worked fine. Anyway I'm pretty sure that the problem is my computer but again I have no ideia why.

Comment: hi @Zuqui -- if the problem is intrinsic to one computer - I'd start poking around your network/firewall settings

Comment: Hi @DavidDaedalus I disabled everything firewall/antivirus, changed network, updated all my network drivers, tried all the suggestions again and still not working. I'm going to try install windows again with platform 86x.

Comment: huh. not sure what to tell you without access to the machine. If it is only that one laptop though - then it might be worth at least googling around to see if there's some issue with your OS/hardware config and maven before going through the bother of reinstalling everything.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem installing Windows again, I didn't find an answer unfortunately.